# Single predicate to test for "self-evaluating" atoms in Clojure

Tags: clojure, predicate

At the home site of [Clojure](http://clojure.org/evaluation), there is the following statement:

> Strings, numbers, characters, true,
>   false, nil and keywords evaluate to
>   themselves.

Is there a single combined predicate that tests for any of these, combining `string?`, `number?`, `char?`, `true?`, `false?`, `nil?`, and `keyword?`. Should I just use `(complement symbol?)`?

Comment: Great question. My thoughts are that there is not a single predicate to do this in the main Clojure API yet. Although there may be in third-party APIs.

Comment: How about evaluating it and checking if it equal to itself :-)

Comment: @mikera: See the answer by Arthur Ulfeldt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but you could use the following to test for any of those conditions and return true if one is true:

```
(defn self-eval?
  [x]
  (or (string? x)
      (number? x)
      (char? x)
      (keyword? x)
      (true? x)
      (false? x)
      (nil? x)))
```

Comment: That is exactly what I did. I was wondering if there is a single predicate that tests for all of them at once.

Comment: FWIW this is less repetitive as `(defn self-eval? [x] (some #(% x) [string? number? char? keyword? true? false? nil?])`.

Comment: @amalloy Thanks for the shorter version. Use of `some` in Clojure is an interesting idiom; nice to see it in use again here, though for absolute beginners I think the `or` version is probably more approachable.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy enough to write a macro that asks "does the given expression evaluate to itself". In fact this is a good example of tasks that can only be done with a macro because they need to see the argument both evaluated and unevaluated.

```
(defmacro selfp [a] `(= ~a (quote ~a)))
#'user/selfp
user> (selfp 1)
true
user> (selfp +)
false
user> (selfp [1 2])
true
user> (selfp '(+ 1 2 3))
false
```

While strings, numbers, characters, keywords, and the booleans are all self-evaluating, other things such as `[1 2]` are as well,so this may not be a useful test in general.

Comment: `(def j 'j) (selfp j)` makes it seem as though symbols are self-evaluating, but of course they're not. I think you're better off with something like semperos's answer.

Comment: @amalloy: In my case, I am using the test in a macro to decide if I need to quote a value or not. If the value evaluates to itself, it really does not matter if it is a symbol or something else. I think I can use the `selfp` as written.

Comment: @Ralph that is very wrong! `selfp` tests whether something evaluates to itself *in the current context*. The macro context will almost always be different from the expansion context; and because `selfp` is a macro it will only work on literals (which you already know whether to quote anyway!). See https://gist.github.com/1056906 for an example: this macro quotes `stuff` correctly, but gets both `:test` and `item` wrong. (in fact, it always quotes anything except the literal symbol `item`)

Comment: @amalloy: Thanks for the example. That explains why my macro is not working. I have written a macro that takes a group of JComponents and GridBagConstraints and builds them into a GridBagLayout. My macro sets some defaults for the GBC, including `(Insets. 5 5 5 5)`. I am trying to get the quoting of the values in my defaults vs. the values "overridden" in the component specifications. I have it working, but only if I write out `(java.awt.Insets. 2 2 2 2)` in my override. I was trying to auto-quote it, but for now, I'll leave it as is. I'll try to come up with a slimmed-down example.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a function that uses a map:

```
(defn myclassifier? [x]
   (let [types-I-care-about #{java.lang.Sring ...}]
      (if (types-I-care-about (type x))
          true
          false)))
```

Another option which may have better performance is to use java's dynamism:

```
(extend-type Object
  IMyClassifier
  (myclassifier? [x]
            (let [c (.getClass x)]
             (if (types-I-care-about (type c))
               (do
                 (extend-type (.getClass x)
                   IMyClassifier
                   (myclassifier? [x] true))
                 true)
               false))))
```

where types-I-care-about is a set of types you care about.